# Python: Extract hrefs inside a div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to write a simple download utility using Python, a language that I haven't worked on. The script should look for hrefs inside a particular div id and as long as there is an href, should call a getfile() function. Here is the sample html source -

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <p><i class="icon-film icon-white"> <a target="_blank" href="/accounting?id=265">Video</a></i></p>
    <p><i class="icon-file icon-white"> <a target="_blank" href="/downloadpdf?id=265&type=pdf">&nbsp;PDF Slides</a></i></p>
    <p><i class="icon-download icon-white"> <a target="_blank" href="/downloadpdf?id=265&type=file">Additional Files</a></i></p>
</div>
```

I intend to use the beautifulsoup module to parse and extract the hrefs. All I have at the moment is something like this -

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
s = f.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)
for a in soup.select('div.home'):
    print a.attrs.get('href')
```

This prints `None` at the moment

Comment: I'm not familiar with beautiful soup either, but might the selector be `'div#home'`?

Comment: what you want to get is it href in a right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding all `href`'s inside class `tab-pane fade in active`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(st)                                             
for a in soup.findAll('div', {"class":"tab-pane fade in active"}):   
    for b in a.findAll('a'):                                         
        print b.get('href')
```

**output**

```
/accounting?id=265
/downloadpdf?id=265&type=pdf
/downloadpdf?id=265&type=file
```

Comment: Can we do the same using the id of the div instead?

Comment: @user1720897 You can do something like `soup.findAll('div', {"id":"home"})` if you want to include the `id` as well